# Does printing of an HTML page re-execute javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, printing-web-page

I'm wondering what is happening when you print an html page in the different browsers (IE9++).

Do the different browsers refresh the page re-executing the javascript (implying re-executing some servers calls) ?

How to know you're refreshing -if - for a print in JS ?

Comment: Who is closing this question, with already 3/4 upvotes !!

Comment: Why closing without even adding a comment ?

Comment: I recommend closing since it is too broad. You are not specific in any way. Not in the browsers, not in examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the page is not refreshed when printed. You can however apply a special stylesheet that is only valid for print use. For example:

```
@media print {
    p { font-family:serif; color: black; font-size:12pt }
}
```

See also http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Comment: Sebastian, the question is also what happens with html events when you apply the css. Are they triggered ?

Comment: What do you mean by html events?

Comment: all events we catch with js (e.g. onclick) : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp

Comment: As long as no one clicks something, why should `onclick` be triggered? I guess the `onbeforeprint` and `onafterprint` will be triggered, but everything else? Don't think so.

Comment: indeed for onclick :-), just wondering if there is a resizing event send (e.g. print page size is not the same as the screen one) or others event when applying the css (hide/unhide)

Comment: Good question. I found another question concerning the resize event: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538260/trigger-resize-event-on-print Empirical result: Sometimes ;)