# How to trigger javascript function when select print preview

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

I use rangeslider to  create a slider component, it looks like below[image]

However, when I ready for print this, in print preview, the slider bar has scale in while slider button position value keep same with the value in html(In html, when window resize, there is a js function to re-calculate the size of bar and postion of slider button).

slider in print preview:
[image]

So my question is, how to call function to re-calculate slider button postion in print preview, like window.resize event.

Appreciate for any comment!!

Comment: Can create jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: Tak a look at [this article](http://tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/). It shows some possible ways how to detect user's request to print. Not sure if you'll be able to alter the appearance of the document afterwards, however. Give it a shot. Nothing to lose, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To detect print requests with [javascript](http://tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/) you can try:

```
var beforePrintFunc = function() {
    ...
}
//for chrome
window.matchMedia('print').addListener(function(mql) {
    if (mql.matches) {
        beforePrintFunc();
    }
});

window.onbeforeprint = beforePrintFunc;
```

To detect after print preview event:

```
var afterPrintFunc = function() {
    ...
}
//for chrome
window.matchMedia('print').addListener(function(mql) {
    if (!mql.matches) {
        afterPrintFunc();
    }
});
window.onafterprint = afterPrintFunc;
```

However, there may be an easier approach as pointed out by @torazaburo in the comment below as long as you are only making styling changes:

```
@media print {
    //your print specific styles go here
}
```

Comment: Instead of doing this, why not add a `@print` media query in your CSS?

Comment: @torazaburo That is a good point. Though OP's question seems to be about how to trigger a javascript `function` before print preview

Comment: Sure, depends on how narrowly you want to interpret his question. It seems somewhat clear that his ultimate goal is to print the slider at a particular size. Installing a hook on `beforePrint` is one particular way to achieve that. A media query is another. The problem with the hook approach is that then after printing is done you probably need to restore the previous size--is there an `afterprint` event for that?

Comment: I added the potentially simpler css approach and have also provided the other half of the javascript approach. Thanks for the feedback @torazaburo.

Comment: It's often impossible to do this using pure CSS. For instance React Grid Layout will only resize on a "resize" event => you need to trigger this event manually before the browsers print the page for the grid to resize, even if your media queries are correctly set.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a jQuery equivalent of the solution proposed by @Moishe Lipsker but with no effect.

That is why for jQuery I make the changes on Print Preview once it is visible, with the following code:

```
$(window).on({
   'beforeprint': () => {
       this.detectPrintPreview();
    },
    'print-preview': () => {
        this.formatDesktopPrintPreview();
    }
});

detectPrintPreview() {
    $('.article-page').trigger('print-preview');
}

formatPrintPreview() {
    console.log('print preview');

    $('.box').appendTo('.example-elem);

}
```