# How to call JavaScript function before load the print preview on IE11 and Edge Browser

Tags: javascript, print-preview

I am calling a JavaScript function adjustHeight() to adjust the height of the div and span on the page. This JavaScript function will call in window.onload() and window.resize() functions. How can I call this function before print preview method called.

I need to adjust the height of the page in print preview mode. For this I need to call this function. This is working fine in Chrome browser using window.onbeforeprint() but not working in IE11 and  Edge browser.

I tried the this solution [How to trigger javascript function when select print preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345745/how-to-trigger-javascript-function-when-select-print-preview) and this only work in Chrome browser but i need this IE11 and chrome browser.

Here is the code working only in Chrome browser.

```
if (window.matchMedia) {
                var mediaQueryPrint = window.matchMedia('print');
                mediaQueryPrint.addListener(function(mql) {
                    if (mql.matches) {
                        //call the height adjustment function
                    } 
                });
            }

window.onbeforeprint = beforePrint;
```

Appreciate for any comment.

Comment: Welcome to SO!, can u provide the code of the wepage you are working on?

Comment: Hi @LuisE,    
please find the code.
if (window.matchMedia) {
                    var mediaQueryPrint = window.matchMedia('print');
                    mediaQueryPrint.addListener(function(mql) {
                        if (mql.matches) {
                            beforePrint();
                        } 
                    });
                }

window.onbeforeprint = beforePrint;

Comment: Please edit the question and put the code you are writing in a formatted way so it will be easier to read and understand :) that would help people get the context faster and help you

Comment: Hi @Odinn, i have edited the original question.